# Handling Node.js Async Returns with "require" (Node ORM)

Tags: node.js, orm, require

I'm using the Node.js ORM module : https://github.com/dresende/node-orm

I'm able to create a model by doing this:

```
    var orm = require("orm");
    var db = orm.connect("creds", function (success, db) {
        if (!success) {
            console.log("Could not connect to database!");
            return;
        }

      var Person = db.define("person", {
        "name"   : { "type": "string" },
        "surname": { "type": "string", "default": "" },
        "age"    : { "type": "int" }
      });
    });
```

The problem is that I want to put Person (and all other models for that matter) in external includes.

If I do something like this:

```
   require("./models/person.js");
```

I can't use the db variable inside of that, because it only exists in the context of the callback function for orm.connect(). I can't move orm.connect to the require (person.js) and do a module.export for the model info, because in the parent script, the require will happen and then the model won't be ready by the next line, since it's not waiting on the callback. IE

```
//person.js
// db and orm get defined up here as before
Person = {}; // code from above, with the define and etc. 
Module.exports = Person;
//app.js 
person = require("./models/person.js");
console.log(person); // returns undefined, connect callback isn't done yet
```

I feel like there's an obvious way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps could make the person.js's export into a function, and pass in db? Like this:

```
//app.js
var orm = require("orm");
var db = orm.connect("creds", function (success, db) {
    if (!success) {
        console.log("Could not connect to database!");
        return;
    }

  var Person = require("./models/person.js")(db);
});

//person.js
module.exports = function(db){
    return db.define("person", {
        "name"   : { "type": "string" },
        "surname": { "type": "string", "default": "" },
        "age"    : { "type": "int" }
    });
}
```

Comment: That is a good point. I was worried about using using globals, I didn't think about passing db to the require. Actually I did, I just didn't realize this was possible. I'm going to try this and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Totally worked, great way to approach it. I think this is what ControlAltDel was going for but I didn't quite get it due to not realizing that you can directly execute the return of the require with an argument that gets passed into the file.

Comment: Then, how do you handle the case when you want to create a relation between two models? Do you pass the model you need as a parameter like this? --> http://pastie.org/4189607 Looks ugly for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the code you have posted here in a function, you can export that and use it in person.js (or the other way around)

Comment: The problem I have here is that putting the orm.connect (represented by var db) callback is not available asynchronously in a require. So if you make it a function, the problem is still that it is called before the the callback returns, or the object returned from the connect is not initialized yet, because it's not waiting on the callback before trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Node-orm is not so good. Node-mysql driver has native implementation, but node-orm do not.
You could use light-orm as wrapper to node-mysql. You will get really flexible models.

https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm and https://npmjs.org/package/mysql