# accessing required modules from other modules

Tags: node.js, module

I have a bare-bone express application, exactly the one that is created with the `express` command.

I have installed socket.io and attached it to my server, like this:

```
var app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = io.listen(server);

server.listen(8000);
```

Now, I also have the routes files, which is called like this:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

Inside this module I have the following function:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  socket.emit('news', { message: "foo" });
};
```

This *obviously* leads to a 500 reference error, because the routes file is an exportable module, and obviously has **no idea** what the socket is, as it is located in the app.js file.

**Is there a way I can access this socket object from this, or any other file?** Please note that it is attached to the express generated app. Here is a link to said project: http://jsfiddle.net/E27yN

---

extra: what about getting/setting session data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what socket object? In the code you posted you don't actually have a socket object. If you mean the io object, you could do a number of things, like passing it as an argument, making it into a singleton (very easy with require) etc. On the other hand, you probably want to emit to specific socket, but as said which one isn't clear from your question.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I still am a newbie with node.js. I am referring to the socket object cited in the socket.io tutorial page: http://socket.io/#how-to-use. Actually, I need to correct my question. I mean the `io` object.

Comment: OK, if you actually mean the `io` object I think you're misunderstanding how Socket.IO works. You cannot `emit` from the `io` object, only from specific socket. You get a socket using the `io.on('connection', function(socket) {})` call and you can call `emit` (or even `broadcast.emit`) on this object.

Comment: Ah, I see, but what if I want to emit without having an `on connection` trigger? Imagine like a user clicking on a like button on facebook: supposedly, the socket is connected already.

Comment: Well, apparently you can actually emit to everybody without having a socket, using `io.sockets.emit`. So if you can just get the io object, you can indeed do what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, I had a very similar problem: [Handling Node.js Async Returns with "require" (Node ORM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669561/handling-node-js-async-returns-with-require-node-orm)

The way I resolved it was by putting a function call to the require, and returning that function in my exports, then that was accessible via that local variable. In your case, I think it'd be something like this:

```
var routes = require("routes.js")(io);
console.log(routes.index()); // will log return of the function "index" in routes.js.

// in routes.js
module.exports = function(io) {
  var exports = this;
  exports.index = function(req,res,io) {
    // now io.socket is available to routes
    console.log(io); 
  }
  return exports;
}
```

Now you can access whatever you've exported by using that variable. So getting and setting session data would be a matter of getting that info to/from the proper place and modifying it in your parent file (usually whatever you're launching with node, like app.js or what have you).

Hope this helps!

EDIT: After discussing this in the comments, I think the problem is you're trying to use express and socket.io on the same port.

The example they give in your link (http://socket.io/#how-to-use) actually shows that they are serving up index.html from app.get("/"). Index.html includes the socket.io script file () which is by default served up when you start your socket server.

That would look like this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lytpx/

Note that you serve up the index.html page through express, but your socket service actually serves up /socket.io.js which then makes connection calls to the listening socket service (note, you may want to change localhost in your io.connect call in index.html to whatever your server is).

Comment: not exactly: I am using `app.get('/', routes.index);` to access the routes, and I need to use `io.sockets`, but I don't know how to access it from there.

Comment: so you're saying routes.index needs to be aware of the value of your io.sockets? If that's the case, this solves that problem but I didn't give you specific enough code.

Comment: no (well, probably) forgive me if I sound dumb I'm just very new to this. Please look at the code in my question: when I am calling `socket.emit` I get a 500 reference error, because in the routes.js file there is no reference of it, since I instanciated all the socket.io stuff in the, main, app.js file which is the one that is calling `app.get('/', routes.index);` I want to be able to do this socket.emit from this routes file

Comment: No it's okay, I am still dumb with this. We all are, Node is new. : )

I think what you need to do is pass your socket object to your routes file when you require it, then you can dynamically set your routes. I'll edit my code example to show you what I mean.

Comment: the edit doesn't work: i am getting "object is not a function"... gosh this is sooo confusing

Comment: Well, I'm only giving you snippets. I'm not sure how the rest of your code works. I saw in your initial example, you're directly modifying exports.index. Typically, the way I write a module is like this: 
    module.exports = function() { return "whatever";};
then, when I require that file, it returns "whatever". I'm not sure how you're doing it in your routes.js file, you may need to give us a little more code.

Comment: have a look at this fiddle, it's exactly what I am doing: http://jsfiddle.net/E27yN/ It's the simples of the setups, almost.

Comment: I was going to move this to chat, but it looks like it's blocked where I am right now. So here's the problem: if you look at their example in express, the "socket" variable they're using is actually being set AFTER they set their routes with express.
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

I don't think you want to set express to listen that way: typically you want to serve up your index file through express and then have socket.io listen on some other socket.

Comment: edited answer, pointing you now to this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Lytpx/

tested in my local environment it works.